# ThisWorkbook.Saveas not working a second time for all users except myself

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I have a new spreadsheet with a macro that saves 2 copies once the data has been updated. Each copy is saved to a slightly different location with a slightly different name. Here's my code:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs file_full, xlOpenXMLWorkbook

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs arch_full, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

`file_full` and `arch_full` are variables with the complete file path and new file name in them like this `"G:\Team\Service\Mapping Report\Mapping Report.xls"`. The difference is the 'arch' one goes to a different folder (an 'Archive' folder in the Mapping Report folder' and has a date appended to the front of the filename.

When I run the code myself, it works perfectly, saving a normal copy and an archive copy with no errors. It's designed to be updated by a few other people but when they run it the get a this error when it tries to save the archive copy:

```
Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed
```

I initially thought it was because it was saving an xls copy of an xlsm workbook but it works perfectly for me.

Could there be something in my Excel settings that's making it work for me but no-one else? Is there a better method of saving these copies that would work for more users?

Comment: What happens when these users try to manually save as with the Excel UI?

Comment: So the file name ends as `.xls` but you chose `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` as format? That's not good as `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` format files should be `.xlsx` only! Check the [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat). • Is the file location on a network or local? Do all folders of the path exist?

Comment: `Debug.Print` / Check the filename it's trying to save the archive file as. If it includes a date, you might be including invalid characters like backslash, depending on their locale? Alternatively, check their folder permissions.

Comment: @CLR You got it. The users date settings were putting slashes in it. I wrote a little more code to convert the date into a format acceptable to use in a file name and it worked :)